# How to add && to onclick and if function in javascript? Thanks alot

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick

So I have a code that looks like this

```
<button id="p1" onclick="p();" >p1</button>
<button id="p2" onclick="p();" >p2</button>
<p id="p3">2</p>
```

And then I would like to make a function that goes

```
function p(e){

    var p= document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML;

    if('p1'==e && p!=2){alert('yes');}

    if('p2'==e && p==2){alert('no');}

}
```

I don't know why it's just not working.

How to use if and `&&` and `onclick` together in this case?

Please guide me further and in javascript only.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a function `p()` that takes in a parameter `e` but when you are calling that function in your `onClick`, you are not passing in any parameters for that `e`.
you can modify your html code as such\

```
<button id="p1" onclick="p('p1');" >p1</button>
<button id="p2" onclick="p('p2');" >p2</button>
<p id="p3">1</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with `if` and `&&` here.
you are not passing any data to the function as attributes.

```
function p(e){ //your function} in this case you have a argument passed.
```

you have to pass the values through

```
<button id="p1" onclick="p(p1);" >p1</button>
<button id="p2" onclick="p(p2);" >p2</button>
```

**If and &&**
as you know if will trigger its body when the argument is true and in case of && both side of the value should be so that the return boolean expression become true

```
true && true ==> true
true && fale ==> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use more descriptive names, since you have a function and a variable both called `p` is a bit confusing.

So I change the code slightly, you have to pass an argument to the function that is triggered by the button so you can detect which button made the call, usually it is an 'event' but you can also use other names like 'this' or 'e'

```html
<button id="p1" onclick="handleOnClick(event)" >p1</button>
<button id="p2" onclick="handleOnClick(event)" >p2</button>
<p id="p3">2</p>
```

Then you compare by getting the id of the element by `event.target.id` like so:

```js
function handleOnClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    
    var p = document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML;
    if('p1'==e.target.id && p==2){alert('yes');}
    if('p2'==e.target.id && p==2){alert('no');}
}
```

Note I change the evaluation on your first `if` from `!=` to `==` other wise that condition will never be true but you can change that to whatever suits your needs.